# Forwarding access to a subset of ssh-agent identitites

Tags: linux, security, ssh

I work for two companies (let's call them RedCorp and BlueCorp).  They both trust me but they don't trust each other, and I don't want to expose either's secrets to the other.

My laptop's ssh-agent has two private keys, one for access to each company.  I can run:

ssh -A redcorp-server1

and access all of redcorp's other servers from there, by virtue of my forwarded agent connection.

Likewise, I can run:

ssh -A bluecorp-server1

and access all of bluecorp's other servers from there.

The problem is that whenever I'm logged into redcorp-server1, the root user there can set his $SSH_AUTH_SOCK to point at my forwarded agent connection, and abuse my other identity to break into BlueCorp.

How can I prevent that?

ssh's IdentitiesOnly option doesn't do what I want.  That only controls which key I offer when authenticating to redcorp-server1; it doesn't change the fact that my forwarded agent connection allows an ssh process on redcorp-server1 to authenticate using any of my identities.

The only solution I've found is to run two separate ssh-agents, and only load one key into each of them.  That's a huge pain though:  There's no way for an ssh_config stanza to specify which of my agents I should use when connecting to a given host.  Instead I've had to make shell aliases on my laptop for each of the two corps which point $SSH_AUTH_SOCK to the right agent before running ssh.  Also, I use rsync and a dozen other tools which use ssh as a transport, and each of them has to be configured using a different syntax to make it invoke ssh in this special way.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this functionality exists. It would be a great idea to write a proxy agent that filters SSH agent requests so that sessions under that proxy could see only a subset of keys. It could probably be made so that it is used as a prefix to the `ssh` command line like `ssh-agent-filter -i allow_this_fingerprint ssh rest-of-command-line`

Comment: Would it be possible to just not use ForwardAgent on your connections?

Comment: It's a bit depressing that this has had so few views and votes.  People are mostly just not aware of the issue.

Answer (score 9):

You can now use multiple agents and specify each specifically using `IdentityAgent` and add the keys you want with `IdentityFile` and set `AddKeysToAgent` to `yes`.  You will have to specify the unix socket for each `ssh-agent` to bind to with the `-a` option.  You could also of course add the keys manually with `ssh-add`, after you create each one.

First create your agent:

`ssh-agent -a ~/.ssh/redcorp-agent`

Then in your `.ssh/config` have something like this:

```
Host redcorp* *.redcorp.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/redcorp.pem
IdentityAgent ~/.ssh/redcorp-agent
AddKeysToAgent yes
ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: I don't understand why this hasn't been voted the "best" answer.  ssh-agent-filter (from the top voted answer) is interesting, but is a third party tool that's not part of OpenSSH.  It's nice to know about, but the solution presented in this answer uses only OpenSSH and improves understanding of SSH, whereas I feel like ssh-agent-filter is obfuscating an otherwise understandable topic behind "magic".

Comment: @TylerAbair because the `IdentityAgent` directive (OpenSSH 7.3 in August of 2016) didn't exist at the time the "best" answer was written in January of 2015.  This newer answer is indeed better, and is steadily gaining votes over time, but it's not because the original audience preferred obfuscation or similar.

Answer (score 7):

I implemented an [ssh-agent-filter](https://github.com/tiwe-de/ssh-agent-filter) for myself, use it with:

```
$ afssh -c id_bluecorp -- server1.bluecorp.com
$ afssh -c id_bluecorp -- server2.bluecorp.com
$ afssh -c id_redcorp -- server42.redcorp.com
```

It's already in Debian (and Ubuntu).

Comment: Sounds like a useful tool. I can think of a couple of features, which would make it even more useful. `1.` Support for adding a key through the filter. `2.` Support for using a key to authenticate to a server without forwarding the key I just used to authenticate to that server. `3.` Support for specifying multiple agents from which the filter can request signatures. (Though the third might be better suited as a separate tool.)

Comment: @kasperd 1.: [added as an issue](https://github.com/tiwe-de/ssh-agent-filter/issues/2) 2: you might tell ssh to use a key without asking the agent or add the key needed for the initial connection as confirmed. for the agent it is impossible to tell apart local from forwarded requests because both come from the local ssh process.

Comment: Telling the ssh client to find the key in a file would work fine, if I had the secret key in an unencrypted file. However my primary reason for using ssh-agent is, that I don't have the key in an encrypted file. I realize that one of the features I was asking for would probably require a modification to the ssh client rather than ssh-agent-filter. If the ssh client would read two different environment variables to find the agent to use for authentication and the agent to use for forwarding, then it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch to openssh that will forward the ssh-agent specified by the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK_FORWARD` environment variable to the remote host and use the usual `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env. var. agent for authenticating to the host.

That means that you can use ssh-agent filter to filter just the key you want available on the remote machine and change the env. var from ssh-agent filter to `SSH_AUTH_SOCK_FORWARD` while leaving all your keys in the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` agent.

You can find the patch here:

https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1937

Hopefully it will be applied to openssh.

Answer (score -3):

I don't get the problem. If you set and export $SSH_AUTH_SOCK to the appropriate value then programs which call ssh should not need any modification. Of course, the target of e.g. an rsync call must be compatible with the selection of the ssh-agent.

Comment: If you don't get the problem, then maybe make a comment about it, but don't put that forward as an answer.  As the OP says, you can't select the agent from an ssh_config stanza.